# Accesing a client area wxWidgets with c++ (Windows)

Tags: c++, windows, wxwidgets

I am a beginner with wxWidget. How can i get access at client area in a wxFrame?

[image: wxWidget]

Client and Non-Client Areas

When we refer to the size of a window, we normally include the outer dimensions, including decorations such as the border and title bar. When we refer to
the size of the client areaof a window, we mean the area inside the window
that can be drawn upon or into which child windows may be placed. A frame’s
client area excludes any space taken by the menu bar, status bar, and toolbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the client areas size: http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_window.html#ae56fc53268b815b58570f66bfc33838f

If you want to draw on the client area: https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Drawing_on_a_panel_with_a_DC